# Kaplansky's formula

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras, projection, von-neumann-algebras

I want to prove the Kaplansky's formula

> For two projections $p, q$, $$(p\lor q)-p\sim q-(p\land q).$$

A step where I'm stuck is in trying to prove that the projection onto the kernel of $(1-p)q$ is $(1-q)+(q\land p)$.

Moreover, how does one find the right support of $(1-p)q$ from above?

If anyone can provide a reference where proof of Kaplansky's formula is explained properly, that'd be useful too!

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti: Huh? The tag "von Neumann algebras" is more than enough for this. Completely standard stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $(1-p)qx=0$. Then
$$
qx=pqx+(1-p)qx=pqx.
$$
So $qx\in (p\land q)\,H$, and then
$$
x=(1-q)x+qx\in \big[(1-q)+(p\land q)\big]\,H.
$$

Right support: if $xp=x$, then $px^*=x^*$. The least such projection is the propjection onto the range. So the right support is
$$
P_{[\ker (1-p)q]^\perp}=1-(1-q)-p\land q=q-p\land q. 
$$

---

The proof I know is the one in Kadison Ringrose II, Theorem 6.1.7.

Comment: And how does one get the right support from this?

Comment: What's the right support?

Comment: Right support of $x$ is defined as the smallest projection $p$ such that $xp=x$.

Comment: Ok, so the computation one needs is the one already done. See the edit.